# Apache Multiple Sites: Show different site to visitors on domain-name than to IP address?

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I want to set up my server for multiple sites but I want a good error message if people try to access them by the IP, is there any way to set this up in httpd.conf? I know you have to use `virtualhosts` but everything wants a `servername` and everywhere I've seen that's been set to a domain, is there any way to set `servername` to an IP to serve alternate content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it goes in [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html), the first defined virtual host becomes *primary* and serves the requests that doesn't match any other virtualhost's ServerName (also, there are many useful examples of different configurations)

Comment: Yeah, my bad... I didn't have an index.html page in there and kept seeing the default "you have a server!" page...